# Converting an rdlc into image in ASP.net MVC3(Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, image, razor, rdlc

In my `asp.net mvc3(Razor)` application i am using `rdlc` for Reporting. For printing purpose i just `need to convert the rdlc into image`. I just tried the following code

```
   public ActionResult FilePrint()
    {
        LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();

        localReport.ReportPath = @"Reports/OP/Rdlc/ClinicInvoiceReceipt.rdlc";

        iClinicInvoiceReceipt = new RmtOPInvoice.ClinicInvoiceReceipt();
        DataTable dt = iClinicInvoiceReceipt.SelectReceiptDtlForPrint(2);

        ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
        reportDataSource.Value = dt;
        reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet1";
        localReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

        string reportType = "Image";
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;
        Warning[] warnings;

        string[] streams;

        byte[] renderedBytes;
        //Render the report

        renderedBytes = localReport.Render(
            reportType,
            null,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);

        return File(renderedBytes, "Image");
  }
```

and in view

```
 <img src="@Url.Action("FilePrint","ClinicInvoiceReceipt")" />
```

But it doesnot works. How can i achieve this? If anybody knows please share..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing DeviceInfo settings. Create a DeviceInfo settings as follows

```
 string deviceInfo =
        "<DeviceInfo>" +
        "  <OutputFormat>JPEG</OutputFormat>" +
        "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
        "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
        "  <MarginTop>0.4in</MarginTop>" +
        "  <MarginLeft>0.6in</MarginLeft>" +
        "  <MarginRight>0.6in</MarginRight>" +
        "  <MarginBottom>0.4in</MarginBottom>" +
        "</DeviceInfo>";
```

and change

```
renderedBytes = localReport.Render(
        reportType,
        null,
        out mimeType,
        out encoding,
        out fileNameExtension,
        out streams,
        out warnings);

return File(renderedBytes, "Image");
```

to

```
renderedBytes = localReport.Render(
        reportType,
        deviceInfo ,
        out mimeType,
        out encoding,
        out fileNameExtension,
        out streams,
        out warnings);

return File(renderedBytes, "image/jpeg");
```

Have a look at [Image Device Information Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155373%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for other image types.